# VB6 - Update multiple rows where the query matches

Tags: vb6

This Query will be used to update multiple rows where it matches... but unable to perform as its not in a loop and ended up adding only the first matched row.

```
rs.Open "SELECT tbl_club_member.Mid, tbl_club_member.BlockFlat, [tbl_block_flat.Size] FROM tbl_club_member INNER JOIN tbl_block_flat ON tbl_club_member.BlockFlat = tbl_block_flat.BlockFlat WHERE ((Mid(tbl_block_flat.BlockFlat,1,2) Like '" & Me.Text2 & "') And ((tbl_club_member.MemberType) like 'Owner'));", cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

MemberID = rs.Fields(0)
Charge = rs.Fields(2) * Me.Text1

    With rs
        .Fields(0) = NextID 'tid
        .Fields(1) = CurDt   'tdate
        .Fields(2) = 72 'accid
        .Fields(3) = MemberID 'memberid
        .Fields(8) = Charge 'amount
        .Fields(9) = Combo2.Text 'particular
        .Fields(10) = userx
        .Fields(11) = Now()
        .Update
    End With
       rs.MoveLast
        Exit Sub
```

Comment: Are you asking how to loop through a RecordSet?

Comment: @Brian M Stafford Yes. This Query will be used to update multiple rows where it matches... but unable to perform as its not in a loop and ended up adding only the first matched row.

Comment: Maybe I do not see the point, but why not use an UPDATE statement instead of a query and a loop?

Comment: I don't see that this code will work as posted.  The query is returning 3 fields, but the attempt at an update is expecting 12 fields (`.Fields(11)`). I'd expect an error to be thrown on the assignment for `.Fields(3)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using UPDATE sql.

```sql
Update tableA SET tableA.fieldA = 'somevalue' WHERE condition;
```

**Loop** and **update** is not recommended, unless you have complex logic in vb code.

There is an class that maybe helpful.

```vb
Option Explicit
'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'@@summary
'@@require
'---Class:CHashTable.cls
'---Import:Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library
'@@reference
'@@license
'@@author sunsoft
'@@create
'@@modify
'---20160812:create this class
'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'//
'//      Public Declare
'//
'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'       Interface
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------


'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'       Public Const
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------


'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'       Public DataType
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------


'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'       Public Variable
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------


'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'       Public API
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------


'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'       Event Declare
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------


'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'//
'//      Private Declare
'//
'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'       Private Const
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------


'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'       Private DataType
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------


'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'       Private Variable
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private m_Conn       As ADODB.Connection

Private m_Command    As ADODB.Command

Private m_ConnString As String

Private m_FilePath   As String

Private m_AutoConnect As Boolean

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'       Property Variable
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------


'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'       Private API
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------


'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'//
'//      Class
'//
'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'       Initialize
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
  m_ConnString = ""
  m_FilePath = ""
  m_AutoConnect = True
End Sub


'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'       Terminate
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
  Set m_Conn = Nothing
  Set m_Command = Nothing
End Sub


'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'//
'//      Events
'//
'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'//
'//      Private Property
'//
'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'//
'//      Private Methods
'//
'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Private Sub OpenConn()
  Set m_Conn = New ADODB.Connection
  m_Conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
  m_Conn.Open ConnectionString
End Sub

Private Sub CloseConn()
  m_Conn.Close
  Set m_Conn = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function m_ApostropheCount(ByVal SQL As String) As Long
'count number of "'"
  m_ApostropheCount = Len(SQL) - Len(Replace(SQL, "'", ""))
End Function

Private Function m_ProcessNameParams(mSQL As String, mDic As CHashTable, mParams() As Variant) As Boolean
  Dim mNewSql As String, mWord As String, mFieldName As String
  Dim mParamCount As Long, i As Long, comaCount As Long
  Dim mBeginParam As Boolean

  If m_ApostropheCount(mSQL) Mod 2 = 1 Then
    Err.Raise 110000000, "Symbal "" '"" must be in pairs,please check SQL statement"
  End If

  'init mDic
  mBeginParam = False
  mFieldName = ""
  mParamCount = 0

  For i = 1 To Len(mSQL)
    mWord = Mid(mSQL, i, 1)
    Select Case mWord
      Case " ", ",", ")"
        mNewSql = mNewSql & mWord
        If mBeginParam Then
          ReDim Preserve mParams(mParamCount)
          mParams(mParamCount) = mDic.Item(mFieldName)
          mFieldName = ""
          mParamCount = mParamCount + 1
        End If
        mBeginParam = False
      Case "'"
        comaCount = comaCount + 1
        mNewSql = mNewSql & mWord
      Case "@"
        If comaCount Mod 2 = 0 Then
          mBeginParam = True
          mNewSql = mNewSql & "?"
        Else
          'odd number of "'" means that "@" is only string of content
          mNewSql = mNewSql & mWord
        End If
      Case Else
        If mBeginParam = False Then
          mNewSql = mNewSql & mWord
        Else
          mFieldName = mFieldName & mWord
        End If
    End Select
  Next i
  'all done but check last word for that last word maybe param
  If mFieldName <> "" Then
    ReDim Preserve mParams(mParamCount)
    mParams(mParamCount) = mDic.Item(mFieldName)
    mFieldName = ""
  End If
  'return
  mSQL = mNewSql
  m_ProcessNameParams = True
End Function

Private Function m_GetVarType(ByRef Value As Variant) As ADODB.DataTypeEnum
  Select Case VarType(Value)
    Case VbVarType.vbString
      m_GetVarType = ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar
    Case VbVarType.vbInteger
      m_GetVarType = ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adSmallInt
    Case VbVarType.vbBoolean
      m_GetVarType = ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adBoolean
    Case VbVarType.vbCurrency
      m_GetVarType = ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adCurrency
    Case VbVarType.vbDate
      m_GetVarType = ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDate
    Case 8209
      m_GetVarType = ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarBinary
    Case Else
      m_GetVarType = ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVariant
  End Select
End Function

'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'//
'//      Inherit
'//
'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'//
'//      Public Property
'//
'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Public Property Get ConnectionString() As String
  ConnectionString = m_ConnString
End Property

Public Property Let ConnectionString(ByVal vNewValue As String)
  m_ConnString = vNewValue
End Property

Public Property Get IsReady() As Boolean
  IsReady = IIf(Len(ConnectionString) > 0, True, False)
End Property

'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'//
'//      Public Methods
'//
'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'---------------------Data Base Connection
Public Function DbConnFromFile(ByVal filePath As String) As ADODB.Connection
  Dim mConn As New ADODB.Connection

  mConn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
  mConn.Open "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & filePath & ";"
  Set DbConnFromFile = mConn
End Function

Public Sub SetConnToFile(ByVal filePath As String)
  m_ConnString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & filePath & ";"
End Sub

Public Sub SetConnToAccdb(ByVal filePath As String)
  m_ConnString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & filePath & ";Persist Security Info=False"
End Sub

Public Sub OpenDB()
  m_AutoConnect = False
  Call OpenConn
End Sub

Public Sub CloseDB()
  m_AutoConnect = True
  Call CloseConn
End Sub
'---------------------Querys
Public Function ExecQuery(ByVal SQL As String) As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim mRes As New ADODB.Recordset

  Set m_Command = New ADODB.Command
  If m_AutoConnect Then
    Call OpenConn
  End If
  m_Command.ActiveConnection = m_Conn
  m_Command.CommandText = SQL
  Set mRes = m_Command.Execute()
  'disconnect from database
  mRes.ActiveConnection = Nothing
  If m_AutoConnect Then
    Call CloseConn
  End If
  Set ExecQuery = mRes
  Set m_Command = Nothing
End Function

Public Function ExecParamQuery(ByVal SQL As String, _
                               ParamArray Params()) As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim mRes As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim mParamArr As Variant, mParam As Variant
  Dim i As Long

  Set m_Command = New ADODB.Command

  If m_AutoConnect Then
    Call OpenConn
  End If
  m_Command.ActiveConnection = m_Conn
  m_Command.CommandText = SQL
  m_Command.CommandType = adCmdText

  mParamArr = Params
  If VarType(Params(0)) = 8204 Then
    mParamArr = Params(0)
  End If

  With m_Command
    For Each mParam In mParamArr
      Dim Para As ADODB.Parameter

      Set Para = .CreateParameter(CStr(i), m_GetVarType(mParam), adParamInput, LenB(mParam))
      Para.Value = mParam
      If VarType(mParam) = vbEmpty Then
        Para.size = 1
      ElseIf VarType(mParam) = vbString Then
        If LenB(mParam) = 0 Then
          Para.size = 1
        End If
      End If
      .Parameters.Append Para
    Next
  End With

  Set mRes = m_Command.Execute()
  mRes.ActiveConnection = Nothing
  If m_AutoConnect Then
    Call CloseConn
  End If
  Set ExecParamQuery = mRes
  Set m_Command = Nothing
End Function

Public Function ExecNamedQuery(ByVal SQL As String, HashedParams As CHashTable) As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim mParams() As Variant
  m_ProcessNameParams SQL, HashedParams, mParams
  Set ExecNamedQuery = ExecParamQuery(SQL, mParams)
End Function

Public Function ExecNonQuery(ByVal SQL As String) As Long
  Dim affectedRows As Long

  Set m_Command = New ADODB.Command
  If m_AutoConnect Then
    Call OpenConn
  End If
  m_Command.ActiveConnection = m_Conn
  m_Command.CommandText = SQL
  m_Command.CommandType = adCmdText
  m_Command.Execute affectedRows
  If m_AutoConnect Then
    Call CloseConn
  End If
  Set m_Command = Nothing
  ExecNonQuery = affectedRows
End Function

Public Function ExecParamNonQuery(ByVal SQL As String, ParamArray Params()) As Long
  Dim i As Long, affectedRows As Long
  Dim mParamArr As Variant, mParam As Variant

  Set m_Command = New ADODB.Command
  If m_AutoConnect Then
    Call OpenConn
  End If
  m_Command.ActiveConnection = m_Conn
  m_Command.CommandText = SQL
  m_Command.CommandType = adCmdText
  mParamArr = Params
  If VarType(Params(0)) = 8204 Then
    mParamArr = Params(0)
  End If
  With m_Command
    For Each mParam In mParamArr
      Dim Para As ADODB.Parameter

      Set Para = .CreateParameter(CStr(i), m_GetVarType(mParam), adParamInput, LenB(mParam))
      Para.Value = mParam
      If VarType(mParam) = vbEmpty Then
        Para.size = 1
      ElseIf VarType(mParam) = vbString Then
        If LenB(mParam) = 0 Then
          Para.size = 1
        End If
      End If
      .Parameters.Append Para
    Next
  End With

  m_Command.Execute affectedRows
  If m_AutoConnect Then
    Call CloseConn
  End If
  Set m_Command = Nothing
  ExecParamNonQuery = affectedRows
End Function

Public Function ExecNamedNonQuery(ByVal SQL As String, HashedParams As CHashTable) As Long
  Dim mParams() As Variant
  m_ProcessNameParams SQL, HashedParams, mParams
  ExecNamedNonQuery = ExecParamNonQuery(SQL, mParams)
End Function

Public Function ExecCreate(ByVal SQL As String) As Variant
  Dim mRes As ADODB.Recordset

  Set m_Command = New ADODB.Command
  If m_AutoConnect Then
    Call OpenConn
  End If
  m_Command.ActiveConnection = m_Conn
  m_Command.CommandText = SQL
  m_Command.CommandType = adCmdText
  m_Command.Execute

  m_Command.CommandText = "SELECT @@identity"
  Set mRes = m_Command.Execute
  If mRes.RecordCount > 0 Then
    ExecCreate = mRes.Fields(0).Value
  Else
    ExecCreate = Empty
  End If
  If m_AutoConnect Then
    Call CloseConn
  End If
  Set m_Command = Nothing
  Set mRes = Nothing
End Function

Public Function ExecParamCreate(ByVal SQL As String, ParamArray Params()) As Variant
  Dim mParamArr As Variant, mParam As Variant
  Dim mRes As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim i As Long

  Set m_Command = New ADODB.Command
  If m_AutoConnect Then
    Call OpenConn
  End If
  m_Command.ActiveConnection = m_Conn
  m_Command.CommandText = SQL
  m_Command.CommandType = adCmdText
  mParamArr = Params
  If VarType(Params(0)) = 8204 Then
    mParamArr = Params(0)
  End If
  With m_Command
    For Each mParam In mParamArr
      Dim Para As ADODB.Parameter

      Set Para = .CreateParameter(CStr(i), m_GetVarType(mParam), adParamInput, LenB(mParam))
      Para.Value = mParam
      If VarType(mParam) = vbEmpty Then
        Para.size = 1
      ElseIf VarType(mParam) = vbString Then
        If LenB(mParam) = 0 Then
          Para.size = 1
        End If
      End If
      .Parameters.Append Para
    Next
  End With

  m_Command.Execute
  m_Command.CommandText = "SELECT @@identity"
  Set mRes = m_Command.Execute
  If mRes.RecordCount > 0 Then
    ExecParamCreate = mRes.Fields(0).Value
  Else
    ExecParamCreate = Empty
  End If
  If m_AutoConnect Then
    Call CloseConn
  End If
  Set m_Command = Nothing
  Set mRes = Nothing
End Function

Public Function ExecNamedCreate(ByVal SQL As String, HashedParams As CHashTable) As Variant
  Dim mParams() As Variant
  m_ProcessNameParams SQL, HashedParams, mParams
  ExecNamedCreate = ExecParamCreate(SQL, mParams)
End Function

Public Function ExecScalar(ByVal SQL As String) As Variant
  Dim mRes As ADODB.Recordset

  Set mRes = ExecQuery(SQL)
  If mRes.RecordCount <= 0 Then
    ExecScalar = Empty
  Else
    ExecScalar = mRes.Fields(0).Value
  End If
  Set mRes = Nothing
End Function

Public Function ExecParamScalar(ByVal SQL As String, _
                                     ParamArray Params()) As Variant
  Dim mRes As ADODB.Recordset

  If VarType(Params(0)) = 8204 Then
    Params = Params(0)
  End If

  Set mRes = ExecParamQuery(SQL, Params)
  If mRes.RecordCount <= 0 Then
    Set ExecParamScalar = Nothing
  Else
    ExecParamScalar = mRes.Fields(0).Value
  End If
  Set mRes = Nothing
End Function

Public Function ExecNamedScalar(ByVal SQL As String, HashedParams As CHashTable) As Variant
  Dim mParams() As Variant
  m_ProcessNameParams SQL, HashedParams, mParams
  ExecNamedScalar = ExecParamScalar(SQL, mParams)
End Function

'---------------------Table Structure
Public Function Tables() As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim mRes As ADODB.Recordset
  If m_AutoConnect Then
    Call OpenConn
  End If
  Set mRes = m_Conn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)
  mRes.ActiveConnection = Nothing
  If m_AutoConnect Then
    Call CloseConn
  End If
  Set Tables = mRes
End Function

Public Function UserTables() As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim mRes As ADODB.Recordset
  If m_AutoConnect Then
    Call OpenConn
  End If
  Set mRes = m_Conn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)
  mRes.Filter = "table_type = 'TABLE'"
  mRes.ActiveConnection = Nothing
  If m_AutoConnect Then
    Call CloseConn
  End If
  Set UserTables = mRes
End Function

Public Function Fields(ByVal TableName As String) As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim mRes As ADODB.Recordset
  If m_AutoConnect Then
    Call OpenConn
  End If
  Set mRes = m_Conn.OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns)
  mRes.Filter = "table_name = '" & TableName & "'"
  mRes.Sort = "ORDINAL_POSITION ASC"
  mRes.ActiveConnection = Nothing
  If m_AutoConnect Then
    Call CloseConn
  End If
  Set Fields = mRes
End Function

Public Function KeyField(ByVal TableName As String) As String
  Dim mRes As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim mKeyFieldName As String
  If m_AutoConnect Then
    Call OpenConn
  End If
  Set mRes = m_Conn.OpenSchema(adSchemaPrimaryKeys)
  mRes.Filter = "table_name = '" & TableName & "'"
  mRes.ActiveConnection = Nothing
  If m_AutoConnect Then
    Call CloseConn
  End If
  If mRes.RecordCount > 0 Then
    mRes.MoveFirst
    Do While Not mRes.EOF
      If mRes.Fields("column_name").Value <> "" Then
        mKeyFieldName = mRes.Fields("column_name").Value
        Exit Do
      End If
    Loop
  End If
  KeyField = mKeyFieldName
End Function

Public Sub ReleaseRecordset(res As ADODB.Recordset)
  Set res = Nothing
End Sub
```